# Single gpu mining on ethpool.org: payback questions

Tags: ether, mining-pools

It has been some 8 hours since I started mining with an RX480. Nothing fancy, just a rig used by me and not used the entire time. Its hashing power is around 24-25 Mh/s.

Partially confused with the "next block estimate" of around 7 years (as provided in http://ethpool.org/miners/myaddress) I am wondering if (please, don't laugh) that is how much it will take for me to mine my first reward. I understand that ethpool uses a special solo mining. I do not mind waiting for some time, but would you perhaps:

a) have an estimate of what is there to expect with this time of processing speed working. That is how much and how often can I expect a payout, especially my first?

b) Would you recommend switching to another mining pool due to my low hashing speed?

Thanks in advance for any info provided.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that - indeed - you will be awarded/find a block in approx. 7 years given your hashing power. You might have noticed that your average hash rate slowly crawls up from 0.0 MH/s to some descent number. As the pool is calibrating based on your incoming data, the 7 years might come further down after some time.

I am mining using a single GTX 1070 which after 24 hours reports 26.4 MH/s, current hash rate 34.8 MH/s and average hash rate 16.2 MH/s, but still growing.

For now I would stick to the pool, because switching a pool will not increase your hash rate. If you expect quicker payouts, then consider getting more hashing power OR switch to a pool which pays out smaller amounts and pays out more often (I guess ultimately the results are equivalent).

Answer (score 2):

I just plugged your 25 MH/s rate into the [coinwarz](https://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency/?sha256hr=9460.00&sha256p=2600.00&sha256pc=0.1000&sha256c=false&scrypthr=110000.00&scryptp=1000.00&scryptpc=0.1000&scryptc=false&x11hr=450.00&x11p=120.00&x11pc=0.1000&x11c=false&quarkhr=450000.00&quarkp=75.00&quarkpc=0.1000&quarkc=false&groestlhr=45.00&groestlp=825.00&groestlpc=0.1000&groestlc=false&blake256hr=11.20&blake256p=600.00&blake256pc=0.1000&blake256c=false&neoscrypthr=400.00&neoscryptp=400.00&neoscryptpc=0.1000&neoscryptc=false&lyra2rev2hr=30.00&lyra2rev2p=600.00&lyra2rev2pc=0.1000&lyra2rev2c=false&cryptonighthr=2800.00&cryptonightp=600.00&cryptonightpc=0.1000&cryptonightc=false&ethashhr=25.00&ethashp=250&ethashpc=0.1000&ethashc=true&equihashhr=1180.00&equihashp=600.00&equihashpc=0.1000&equihashc=false&e=CEX.io) calculator which suggests you'll get an expected 0.006 ether/day. However, since it appears that ethpool pays out a full block to the "next in line" when it finds a share, the expected value should be almost the same as the actual value -- except you're not paid until you've accumulated 5 ether (a full block). Thus, it'll take you ~830 days right now (maybe you've already been mining for a while, though, at lower difficulty) to find a block, ignoring the Ethereum difficulty bomb. In practice, if you started mining on the pool today, I'd say there's a pretty decent chance you will *never* receive a payout because, even without the difficulty bomb, proof of stake might replace proof of work (AKA mining) before your first payout.